# How to prevent Android WebView render elements before DOMContentLoaded is fired?

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I'm using android `WebView` and modifying some elements visibility (`document.getElementById('someid').style.display = 'none';`) in JS `DOMContentLoaded` event. However WebView performs rendering **before** DOMContentLoaded is fired and i can see the element visible and then it's hidden.

How to prevent Android WebView from rendering elements before DOMContentLoaded is fired? Any another JS events, webview callbacks, ticks?

Answer (score 0):

You could hide it by default, and then manipulate its visibility upon DOM ready.

Comment: unfortunately i don't have access to page html/css body so i can't set it hidden by default.

Comment: He probably meant the whole webview `webView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`

Comment: Probably he meant it. But it's not good - loading can take some time and control background will be different from page background.